# Ios get UI element from storyboard in android studio

Tags: android, ios, android-studio

I'm working on an android and ios app. I use android studio with intel multi os engine to be able to make the ios one from android studio. My android app works fine. I made the design of the ios part on xcode (because I couldn't make the multi-os designer work for some reasons) and I can't make work a simple label text change from pressing a button. Any ideas how to do this ?

Feel free to ask for more details if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add touchUp action of button like this:

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.lblFormat.text = "Label Text"
    }
```